# variables in groovy how to set a condition by variable type

Tags: groovy

I'm a total newbie and I'm looking for some advice.
how to make a condition in Groovy so that if the variable is a string, then one action is performed, and if the sheet is another
and just as it is necessary to do, if the variable is equal to zero, then nothing is transmitted

````
 //aditionalArgs= "test1 = add1 , tets2= add2 "
aditionalArgs = ["test1=arg1", "test2=arg2"]
println(aditionalArgs.class)

def args = ""

if ((aditionalArgs != "class java.lang.String" ) || (aditionalArgs > 0)){
 def list = aditionalArgs.replace("--build-arg", "").split(',')
  list.each { val->
      args += " --build-arg $val"
  }
  
  println(args.replace("",""))
}

if (aditionalArgs == "ArrayList" ){
 def list = aditionalArgs("--build-arg", "").split('[' , ']')
 list.each { val-> 
     args += " --build-arg $val"
}

  println(args.replace("",""))
}

else(aditionalArgs.length() > 0){
  println "empty aditionalArgs"
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (aditionalArgs instanceof String && aditionalArgs.length() > 0) {
    ...
} else if (aditionalArgs instanceof List && aditionalArgs.size() > 0) {
    ...
} else {
    println "unsupported arg type '${aditionalArgs?.getClass()}' or value '${aditionalArgs}'"
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to add  ```if (aditionalArgs instanceof List) > 0 ?```

Comment: What do you want to check? Size of the list?

Comment: no, I want that if the arguments were passed by the list, there was one solution, if the string was different, and if the argument is empty, then nothing was presented

Comment: ```if (aditionalArgs instanceof String) && (aditionalArgs > 0){```  
should i add something like this?

Comment: it's not clear what you are checking by `aditionalArgs > 0` - length of the string?

Comment: in the end, I need to describe 3 options for work ```aditionalArgs = "--build-arg test1, test2"``` and  ```aditionalArgs = ["test1=arg1", "test2=arg2"]``` and  ```aditionalArgs = ""```

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that you rather want to use a `switch` op:

```
switch( aditionalArgs ){

  case String:
    // do stuff with String
    break

  case List:
    // do stuff with (Array)List 
    break

  case Number:
    // do something with Number
    break

  default:
    throw new Exception( 'I have no idea' )
}
```

More on the statement is [in the docs](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html)